# Options in collapsible dropdown in Panel is not hidden when pressed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I want to have a few dropdowns in a panel using `react-bootstrap`. However, when I clicked the last dropdown, the options are hidden by the panel. Is there anyway to resolve this?

```
<Panel eventKey="1">
  <Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 1</Panel.Title>
  </Panel.Heading>
  <Panel.Body collapsible> <DropdownButton
    bsStyle="default"
    title="No caret"
    noCaret
    id="dropdown-no-caret"
  >
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem divider />
    <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
  </DropdownButton>
  </Panel.Body>
</Panel>
```